# Prevent clang-format from breaking a line at -> operator

Tags: c++, clang-format

The following file `test.cpp`

```
int func() {
   aaaaaaaaaaa = bbbbbbbb->cccccc(SomeNamespace::Function(dddddddd?"eeeeeeeee":"fffffffffff")).gggggggggg();
}
```

is formatted with `clang-format` in the following way (I tried different styles):

```
$ for s in LLVM Google Chromium Mozilla WebKit; do clang-format -style="{BasedOnStyle: $s, ColumnLimit: 80}" test.cpp; done
int func() {
  aaaaaaaaaaa = bbbbbbbb
                    ->cccccc(SomeNamespace::Function(dddddddd ? "eeeeeeeee"
                                                              : "fffffffffff"))
                    .gggggggggg();
}
int func() {
  aaaaaaaaaaa = bbbbbbbb
                    ->cccccc(SomeNamespace::Function(dddddddd ? "eeeeeeeee"
                                                              : "fffffffffff"))
                    .gggggggggg();
}
int func() {
  aaaaaaaaaaa = bbbbbbbb
                    ->cccccc(SomeNamespace::Function(dddddddd ? "eeeeeeeee"
                                                              : "fffffffffff"))
                    .gggggggggg();
}
int
func()
{
  aaaaaaaaaaa =
    bbbbbbbb
      ->cccccc(SomeNamespace::Function(dddddddd ? "eeeeeeeee" : "fffffffffff"))
      .gggggggggg();
}
int func()
{
    aaaaaaaaaaa = bbbbbbbb
                      ->cccccc(SomeNamespace::Function(
                          dddddddd ? "eeeeeeeee" : "fffffffffff"))
                      .gggggggggg();
}
```

I wonder if there is an option to prevent `clang-format` from breaking the line at the `->` operator.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any option only affecting `operator->` in the [list of `clang-format` options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), but you can always disable `clang-format` for the offending lines:

```
int func() {
   // clang-format off
   aaaaaaaaaaa = bbbbbbbb->cccccc(SomeNamespace::Function(dddddddd?"eeeeeeeee":"fffffffffff")).gggggggggg();
   // clang-format on
}
```

This disables formatting completely, so some manual intervention may be necessary if other formatting rules are desired for the lines in question.

Comment: Thanks @You, but it's not very useful for me as I'm trying to beatify a rather large code base.